# Simplest autoscaling kubernetes setup without virtual/overlay networks

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use kubernetes on Hetzner cloud in an auto-scaling setup. Because I'm using cloud VMs, and also because my application architecture allows me to do so, I see no point in running multiple pods or multiple containers on the same node.

Therefore, is it possible to have k8s setup in such a way that it doesn't use any virtual/overlay networking? Since every node anyways gets a separate public and private IP, can the docker containers and k8s use the node's private IP directly for networking?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Answer (score 0):

With no dedicated server, this is possible with Hetzner Cloud Controller Manager with [network support](https://github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager#networks-support). Instead of Flannel it is better to use Cillium for CCM network support, but the choice is yours. More details can be fond [here](https://github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/deploy_with_networks.md).